# check inputfields on pageload and manipulate with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

When I press ADD, I show the hidden `#box`, I hide the ADD button and show the REMOVE button.

html:

```
<input type="button" id="add" value="ADD">
<input type="button" class="no-display" id="remove" value="REMOVE">

<div class="no-display" id="box">
    <input id="a" value="" type="text" />
    <input id="b" value="" type="text" />
    <input id="c" value="" type="text" />
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#add,#remove').click(function () {
    $('#add').toggle();
    $('#remove').toggle();
    $('#box').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

see working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7gRTU/)

Now, I want to check if the input fields `#a` or `#b` or `#c` have a value. If they have a value, on pageload I want to show `#box`, hide the `#add` button and show the `#remove` button.

What is the best way to do this?

you can see a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UtJYY/) here (not finished)

Comment: This is not really a question, but instead you're asking for somebody else to do the work for you. You should post what you've tried first.

Comment: @FelipeBrahm i think the code he tried is there in the fiddle :)

Comment: what if just `#a` has a value.. the `#box` container should show with rest  of the input empty ??

Comment: it is important to show #box and replace the #add button when only one input has a value (or 2 or all)

Comment: @bipen: oh you're right. anyway, bernte you should always include all the code related to your question in the question itself, not links, so that it will always be there, even if the links stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `filter()` to get the count of the input that has value on it... if count is greater that 0 ..means atleast one input is not empty so.. hide add, show remove buttons and the container

try this

```
$('#add,#remove').click(function () {
  $('#add').toggle();
  $('#remove').toggle();
  $('#box').slideToggle("fast");
});

var count = $('#a,#b,#c').filter(function () {
  return $(this).val().length > 0;
}).length;

if (count > 0) {
  $('#box').show();
  $('#add').hide();
  $('#remove').show();
}
```

updated as per comment

```
var count = $('#a,#b,#c').filter(function () {
  return this.value.length > 0; //faster 
}).length;
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UtJYY/14/)

Comment: `this.value.length > 0` would be faster, and just as compatible cross-browser.

Comment: yes agreed... no need of creating jQuery object too... but  i don't think the difference(faster,slower) will be visible here....anyways will be updating my answer.. why create an extra jquery object when you can get it from the DOM rite...

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Move toggle code to a function. Bind it to the click. Call it on load if any of the inputs have a value.

```
$(function () {
  var toggleBox = function () {
    $('#add').toggle();
    $('#remove').toggle();
    $('#box').slideToggle("fast");
  };

  $('#add,#remove').click(toggleBox);
  if(!!$("#a, #b, #c").filter(function() {return this.value;}).length) {
    toggleBox();
  }
});
```